# how to get script variable in a php variable

Tags: javascript, php

i am getting value from ajax in a script variable. i want to store it in php variable for further use. here i am getting keyname as a script variable. i want to call it in php variable

---

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#AttorneyEmpresa").change(function(){
        alert($('#AttorneyEmpresa option:selected').val());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',               
            data:  {keyname:$('#AttorneyEmpresa option:selected').val()}                
        });
    });
});    
</script>
```

---

```
<select name="data[Attorney][empresa]" id="AttorneyEmpresa">
<option value="">---Select---</option>    
<? 
   $sql=mysql_query("select * from master");
   while($sha=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
   <option value="<? echo $sha['id']; ?>"><? echo $sha['name']; ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Use full php tag `<?php     ?>` and dont use `mysql_*`

Comment: Use `$_POST['keyname']`. Also don't need to look for selected option ... can use `data:  {keyname:$(this).val()}` to get value from the `<select>` itself

Comment: i am not getting value in $_POST['keyname']

Comment: Try this `$('#AttorneyEmpresa').val()`

Comment: i am asking how to get keyname in php variable

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that:  The PHP code is run on the server, before the page is sent to the browser.  The Javascript code is run on the client, after it's sent to the browser.  What you're asking for is a time machine where a later action can affect an earlier one.

Comment: how to do if i want selected option of select tag in a php query

Comment: Once the form is submitted, the form handler can use the selection, but not until the form is submitted.